# Do i have to store mails in db?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Are received mails stored somewhere in google app engine app or have i to store it with separated db class?

Answer (score 3):

No, you don't need to store mails in the datastore. Incoming emails generate http requests and  you just need to associate script handlers to email addresses. See the [documentation](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/receivingmail.html).

Comment: Although if you want to read the emails rather than just having your application do something with them immediately, yes, you need to store them because they're not stored anywhere automatically.